# Smoothness of fibers over finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, finite-fields, birational-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of smooth projective varieties over a finite field of characteristic different from $2$. Is there any result on the existence of a point $y\in Y$ such that $X_y = f^{-1}(y)$ is smooth or at least that says something about the singularities of $X_y$?

In the case I am interested in $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m$ is a smooth subvariety $Y = \mathbb{P}^m$ and the fibers of the projection $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^m$ are intersections of two quadrics. I would like to conclude that $f$ has at least one smooth fiber or also that there is at least a fiber of $f$ that is not a cone over a smaller dimensional variety.

Comment: It can happen (only in positive characteristic) that $X$ and $Y$ are smooth, but no fibre is. For example, quasi-elliptic surfaces exist in characteristic $2$ and $3$, meaning $E \to C$ with $E$ and $C$ smooth, and the general fibre a cuspidal cubic. The problem is that a regular variety over the function field $k(C)$ need not be geometrically regular (i.e. smooth).

Comment: On the other hand, the generic fibre $X_{\eta_y}$ is regular when $X$ is regular, as it is a localisation. This should prevent the generic fibre from being a cone, but I don't know if that is enough for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn It depends on the definition of "cone". Every singular quadric is a cone, so if you take a regular but nonsmooth quadric, it will appear as a cone over some inseperable extension.

Answer (score 6):

For your first question, the answer is negative, regardless of the characteristic, because the Frobenius morphism of any positive-dimensional smooth projective variety is a counterexample.

For the second question, I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you. I was implicitly assuming the varieties to be smooth and the characteristic to be not two.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that $X$ is smooth, otherwise the result need not be true. Assuming this, then over $\mathbb C$ this is Bertini's theorem, so you seem to be looking for a Bertini-type theorem over finite fields. There are many papers with such results, for example:

- Poonen, Bjorn; Bertini theorems over finite fields. Ann. of Math. (2) 160 (2004), no. 3, 1099–1127
- Erman, Daniel; Wood, Melanie Matchett; Semiample Bertini theorems over finite fields. Duke Math. J. 164 (2015), no. 1, 1–38
- Charles, François; Poonen, Bjorn; Bertini irreducibility theorems over finite fields. J. Amer. Math. Soc. 29 (2016), no. 1, 81–94
- Asgarli, Shamil; Ghioca, Dragos; A Bertini type theorem for pencils over finite fields. Finite Fields Appl. 77 (2022), Paper No. 101936, 13 pp.

Comment: These results are about Bertini theorems for hypersurfaces in a variety. This can be proved using the smoothness theorem fibers of a morphism, but isn't the same theorem, and in particular I don't know how to go the other way to get results on fibers from these references.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks for the comment. I wasn't sure to what extent these results could be adapted to the fiber case, although I was hoping that the last reference that I listed might help.